# Copying a Running Physical Server to Virtual Box

Tags: server, virtualbox, rsync

I have a server running Ubuntu 10.04. As I want to test some maintenance work, such as upgrading to 12.04, I thought I should create a VM copy of the server using Virtual Box. I don't have a physical access to the server, so I considered the following options: I do

- `dd`'ing the entire hard disk to a raw image on my pc and then creating a VDI out of the raw `dd` image.
- Installing the same ubuntu version, install update and mount the VDI locally and rsync the filesystem from the server to the mounted VDI creating a logical copy of the server.

The rsync solution is a bit more complicated, but seems to save bandwidth, and allows me to create a "copy" of the server with slightly different configuration (e.g. smaller disk).

What do you think is the best way to do so? One of the above methods? A different one?

Comment: Why do you want to do all this just for making a copy of the system? You can try creating image using Norton Ghost / Acronics etc and restore it to the VM. Another way is, using vmware vsphere converter to convert the physical server to a vmware esxi/server/workstation virtual machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rsync` directly turned out to be more problematic than I first thought:

1. The command needs to be run as root on the remote machine.
2. I didn't won't to enable remote root login.
3. The filesystem in based on LVM and it was a hassle to mount the actual root partition of the VM from inside the LVM in the VDI file.

For these reasons I ended up with a 2 step process:

1. Copy all the files from the remote machine to the local host machine.
2. Copy the files to the guest.

I finally went with basic `tar`, although I could have used `rdiffdir` provided by `duplicity` to save some bandwidth.

I started out by setting up an SSH tunnel which I could use to tunnel the `tar` files so I wouldn't have to write the archive to the filesystem I was copying.

```
local$ ssh user@remote -R 3000:localhost:3000
loacl$ nc -l 3000 > filesystem.tar.gz
remote$ sudo tar -vcz / --exclude={/dev,/proc,/sys,/tmp} | nc localhost 3000
```

This created a tar archive of the entire filesystem in my local host machine. The next step was to untar it on the guest:

```
guest$ cd /
guest$ nc -l 3000 | sudo tar -xvz
local$ nc guest_ip 3000 < filesystem.tar.gz
```

In my case `/etc/fstab` referenced filesystems by their UUIDs, so I had to update it with the output of `guest$ sudo blkid`. I also had to update the networking settings in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` (interface names) and `/etc/network/interfaces` (ip addresses).

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly the `dd`-approach or creating an otherwise image of the server is likely to have bandwith issues in case you only have remote access to the server.

Installing Ubuntu 10.04 server to a VDI only to be able to copy an existing installation also is not really needed (but it may save some bandwith).

Let me suggest the following approach:

- Create a Virtual Machine with an **empty** virtual hard disk of desired size.
- Boot the VM with any **live** (Ubuntu) system from an .iso file.
- Partition the hard drive (include boot flag and format with the same file system your old server has).
- Mount this partition to your live environment.
- Copy all files from the old server to the yet empty partition of your VM

  ```
  rsync -avze ssh user@host:/ /<mountpoint>
  ```
- Install Grub resp. Grub2 to the MBR of the now populated VDI drive.
- Reboot.